# PatsyError: Error evaluating factor for 'dependent variable'

Tags: python, statsmodels

Im running the following code and get a Pasty error for the first dependent variable. 
Have looked at all other Pasty examples but none of them worked for me

Following is an example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import math, numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

This is the function:

```
def predict(required_data):

    tot_data = pd.read_csv("file_path_here")

    #home and away are two categorical variables 

    X = tot_data[['home', 'away', 'range', 'blocks']]
    X = pd.get_dummies(X)  
    y = tot_data[['tot']]
    data_formula = pd.concat([X,y], axis=1)



    formula = 'tot ~ range + blocks + home_A + home_B + home_C + away_A + away_B + away_C' 

    model =smf.glm(formula=formula, data=data_formula, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()

    required_data = pd.DataFrame(required_data)

    test_data = required_data[['home', 'away']]

    predict = model.predict(test_data[['home','away']])

return predict
```

This is the function call part:

```
test_data = pd.read_csv(pd.read_csv("file_path_here")
required_data = test_data[:300][['home', 'away', 'date', 'Id']]
required_pred = predict(required_predictions, data_loader)
```

This is the error i get:

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'range' is not defined
```

If I swap range with tot and have tot as dependent variable the NameError will be for 'tot'

Dataframe looks like this:

```
d = {'home_A':[0,1,0,0,0],'home_B':[0,0,1,0,0],'home_C':
    [0,0,0,1,0],'away_A':[0,0,0,0,1],
    'away_B':[1,0,0,0,0],'away_C':[0,1,0,0,0],'range': 
    [15,-4,13,6,-12],'blocks':[6,12,4,8,9]}

print(pd.DataFrame(d))
```

Comment: Can you show us what the dataframe looks like?

Comment: edited an example code of how the df looks like

Comment: And in your actual code is return predict indented that way?

Comment: yes i want the function to return 'tot' which is calculated in predict = model.predict(...)

Comment: Fixed it. Got rid of the 'R' style formula for dependent and independent variables and listed them separately as y and X in the model:

model =smf.glm(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()